# Finding the middle number(s) of an arrayList

Tags: java, median

Given the Intgers:

> 1)ArrayList1:  3456
>
> 2) ArrayList2: 78910

What would be the best way to find the middle numbers if these were imputed as integers of an ArrayList?

I was thinking a.size()/2 (given a is the name of the ArrayList)

i want too return the middle number(s) for the set of integers for the fist example this would be 45 and for the second example this would be 891

What would be the checks if the ArrayList were even or odd?
i was thinking if the size of the Arraylist is odd then add the next integer to the list of integers?
Ive tried this ut but i keep going in circles. i also don't want to sort my list.

Any Clues?

Comment: Which will be your middle number if the size of the arraylist is 10 ? means even size list ?

Comment: When you say "Middle" numbers. Do you mean the numbers in the middle of the array (i.e. the 5th number in an array of 9) or do you mean the middle in order of size?

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean - you've given two integers... are they the contents of the `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Fogmeister sorry i wasnt clear i mean the middle set of integers so for the first example this would be 45 and for the second this would be 8910

Comment: `someInt % 2` should return 1 if odd, and 0 if even.

Comment: why not only 9 in the second case?

Comment: It's still no clear what you mean by "middle numbers". How can 8910  possibly be the middle numbers of 78910. That makes no sense.

Comment: @SpiderPig he wrote in his question that it should be 891, but still, I don't understand what Marcello wants to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you just need to cut off first and last...

```
out.remove(0);
out.remove(out.size()-1);
```

But first test that your list size is bigger then 2.

Comment: Don't you mean bigger than 1? A zero length result would bf correct for a list of length 2

Comment: viewing the requirements i deducted bigger 2... but bigger then 1 will work too.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to remove the forst and last element in the ArrayList you can do it this way.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(Arrays.asList(7,8,9,1,0));
list.remove(list.size()-1);
list.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than thinking about what you're including, think about what you're *excluding*: the two end numbers, which can be referenced without knowing if the length is odd or even:

```
List<Integer> middle = list.subList(1, list.length() - 1);
```